# cardboard flute - cardboard thickness

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, displacement, vector-mapping

I need to prepare a textured simple, plane of cardboard, made of a simple mesh plane but using only, for example, solidify and subdivision modifiers. The thickness I've made as a second material on the object's rim with transparency. In real - cardboard has empty spaces between waves and two planes - spaces that look like holes.

[image: plane with mofifiers]
[image: modifiers]
[image: textures]
[image: transparency texture]
[image: node editor]

From the right angle, as a fake, it looks quite nice :P
But it's not a solution:

[image: no displacement] [image: fake]

Unfortunately, this problem occurs when I try to use displacement...
[image: displacement]

Help ;)

(edit)

My intention is to fold the cardboard into a cardboard box during animation close-ups of the camera. The plane must be rigged and the edge of the cardboard looks photorealistic and unfortunately also in high resolution

---

Thank you all for the advice. Unfortunately, my intention is to fold the cardboard into a cardboard box during animation during close-ups of the camera. The plane must be rigged and the edge of the cardboard look photo realistic and unfortunately in high resolution
[image: rigging]

Comment: Try lowering the "Dicing scale" of the subdivision modifier, be careful not to overdo it, that can lag your computer with too low a value

Comment: Are you bound to using mesh only, or can you use a curve object to get your corrugated pattern?

Comment: I just don't know how to approach it ;)
So far, I've tried to use Rim in Solidify Modifier as a second material, because I have to fold the cardboard surface into a cardboard box during the animation

Answer (score 5):

Single face displacement will only get you so far.
Just to illustrate.

### Single face displacement

The *image texture* is used to "extrude" the original face.
Notice the incomplete rims, rough appearance, and high required geometry.
*Faces: 1 000 000*

[image]

### Multiple Faces

Three faces on top of each other.
Displacement is used on the middle face only, to creating the wavy pattern.
Top and bottom faces have solidify modifier to add thickness.
*Faces: 1000*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but these are not solutions in my situation: /
I would like to fold the cardboard in a carton during animations at close-ups

Comment: Hello again :). To get relevant answers concerning animation, you should edit your original question - it says nothing about animating.

Comment: Well, I should actually start with the target need, sorry: D
now everything should be clear

Answer (score 0):

I would make the squiggle with a separate mesh in between the two side planes. If you do still want to use the displacement modifier, you will need to use more subdivisions or a higher resolution mesh. Hope this helps.

Comment: In this particular situation, unfortunately, this is not a solution to build it from a few meshes, but thank you :)